Issue with Stm32 with out can analyzer
I’ve developed a program that controls a relay based on CAN (Controller Area Network) inputs. Currently, the program depends on CAN analyzer software to establish all connections. I’m looking to eliminate this dependency by integrating the connection setup directly into my program. an
I have tried running the following code and get message sent successfully message but no response from relay
import can
def send_can_message():
    try:
        # Initialize the CAN interface
        bus = can.interface.Bus(channel=0, bustype='ixxat',bitrate=10000)

        # Create a CAN message
        message = can.Message(
            arbitration_id=0xF5,
            data=[0x02, 0x00],
            is_extended_id=False
        )

        # Send the CAN message
        bus.send(message)
        print("Message sent successfully.")

    except can.CanError:
        print("Message failed to send.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_can_message()


As in, you'll still use the same CAN adapter (IXXAT by the looks of it) but you wish to use the API instead? I find it quite handy to buy a 2 channel USB-to-CAN adapter so that I can use one channel for my program and the other as passive listen-only with CANAnalyzer, for monitoring and trouble-shooting.
